# Bundle Node.js backend - Good practice or bad practice?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, browserify

I was wondering - I see the benefits of bundling client side code, but is bundling server side code using Browserify/Webpack considers good practice?

Comment: Performance will be the same. It may increase loading speed, however i think require("sth") is much more easy to read

Comment: I see no real reason to. Webpack is for bundling files so the browser does not have to do so many requests to the server. Yeah, it can be done, but should it? No.

Comment: node.js already has a good module system, with internal caching and all that jazz...

Comment: One reason to bundle on the server is because you want to render React on the server. Since JSX isn't valid JS, you either have to use `babel-node`, or bundle using `babel-loader`. Also, if you are doing SSR in development, then you might want to use HMR so that your React components update on changes. Otherwise you'd have to restart your dev server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but is bundling server side code using Browserify/Webpack considers good practice?

It is definitely note standard. But people do it for "deploy one file" vs. "deploy `src` folder + `package.json` + run `npm install`".

Most devs are used to the `npm install` / `npm start` workflow and don't use webpack for backend stuff.